# I'm trying to add a value to individual characters

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, arraylist, char

I'm working on a Scrabble assignment and I'm trying to assign values to letters. Like in Scrabble, A, E, I, O, U, L, N, S, T, R are all equal to 1. I had some help in figuring out how to add the score up once I assign values, but now I'm trying to figure out how to assign values. Is there a way to create one variable for all the values? That doesn't really make sense to me.

I was also thinking I could do an if-else statement. Like if the letter equals any of those letters, value = 1, else if the letter equals D or G, value = 2 and so on. There are 7 different scores so it's kind of annoying and not efficient, but I'm not really sure what a better way might be. I'm new to programming, a novice, so I'm looking for advice that takes my level into account.

I have started my program by reading words from a text file into an arraylist. I successfully printed the arraylist, so I know that part worked. Next I'm working on how to read each character of each word and assign a value. Last, I will figure out how to sort it.

Answer (score 0):

it's me from the other question again. You can definitely do an if-statement, but if I'm not wrong Scrabble has 8 different values for letters, so you would need 8 “if”s and also since there are around 25 letters (depending on language) you would have to handle all 25 some way in the if-statements which would be quite clunky in my opinion.

I think the best option is to use a Hash-table. A hash-table is basically like a dictionary where you look up a key and get a value. So I would add each letter as a key and keep the corresponding value as the value. It would look like this:

```java
//initialize empty hash map
Hashtable<String, Integer> letterScores = new Hashtable<>();


//now we can add values with "put"
letterScores.put("A",1)
letterScores.put("B",3)
letterScores.put("X",8)
//etc
```

To access an element from the hash table we can use the "get"-method.

```java
//returns 1
letterScores.get("A")
```

So when looping through our word we would essentially get something like this to calculate the value of the word:

```java
int sumValue = 0;
for(int i =0; i < word.length(); i++)}
       sumValue += letterScores.get(word.charAt(i))
}
```

For each character we grab the value entry from the letterScores hash table where we have saved all our letter's corresponding values.

Comment: Thank you for that. Unfortunately, I can't use a hash table because it's outside the scope of my class. I thought maybe I'd use switch instead of if statements. It will be a bit cleaner, but still cumbersome. At the moment, I'm having trouble accessing the chars from the strings in my ArrayList, so I have to figure that out.

Comment: @ScarletCas I see. Yes, switch also works and as you say it is probably a bit better than the many if statements. What problem do you have with accessing the chars? In the loop, does it not work to access the characters with charAt ?

Comment: I figured it out! I was reading the word only. I needed to create a second for loop to read the chars. Silly mistake. Thank you for your help! Now I'm moving on to the sorting part, using a comparator. I'm sure I'll post for help with that soon. Lol.